# Product catalog's sellabe item - index in Sitecore_Web_Index

Tags: sitecore-commerce

We have created a version of sellable items in the product catalog. It is in the draft mode. When I search the same item, we found two different items in the sitecore_web_index. One for the earlier version and another is for draft version.

As per my understanding, once the product catalog will be approved and published, it should go to the sitecore_web_index.

Please can somebody will help me in not getting index of the draft version of the sellable item.

Answer (score 7):

This is controlled by the **Sitecore.Commerce.Core.IgnorePublishedPolicy**, if the environment you're passing in your request contains this policy then both published & unpublished entities will be returned in any requests.

Out of the box the *HabitatAuthoring* environment contains this policy, whereas the *HabitatShops* doesn't.

To make sure you get the correct values in your indexes your crawlers should pass in *HabitatAuthoring* for the master index and *HabitatShops* for your web index.

Out of the box the master index definition includes these default crawlers...

```
<crawler type="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Crawlers.CatalogsCrawler, Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect" patch:source="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connectors.Index.Solr.config">
  <ItemsToTake>100</ItemsToTake>
  <ListName>Catalogs</ListName>
  <IndexListName>CatalogsIndex</IndexListName>
  <Environments hint="list">
    <environment>HabitatAuthoring</environment>
  </Environments>
  <Database>master</Database>
</crawler>
<crawler type="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Crawlers.CategoriesCrawler, Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect" patch:source="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connectors.Index.Solr.config">
 <ItemsToTake>100</ItemsToTake>
  <ListName>Categories</ListName>
  <IndexListName>CategoriesIndex</IndexListName>
  <Environments hint="list">
    <environment>HabitatAuthoring</environment>
  </Environments>
  <Database>master</Database>
</crawler>
<crawler type="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Crawlers.SellableItemsCrawler, Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect" patch:source="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connectors.Index.Solr.config">
  <ItemsToTake>100</ItemsToTake>
  <ListName>SellableItems</ListName>
  <IndexListName>SellableItemsIndex</IndexListName>
  <Environments hint="list">
    <environment>HabitatAuthoring</environment>
  </Environments>
  <Database>master</Database>
</crawler>
```

The Web index includes these default crawlers...

```
<crawler type="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Crawlers.CatalogsCrawler, Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect" patch:source="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connectors.Index.Solr.config">
  <ItemsToTake>100</ItemsToTake>
  <ListName>Catalogs</ListName>
  <IndexListName>CatalogsIndex</IndexListName>
  <Environments hint="list">
    <environment>HabitatShops</environment>
  </Environments>
  <Database>web</Database>
</crawler>
<crawler type="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Crawlers.CategoriesCrawler, Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect" patch:source="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connectors.Index.Solr.config">
  <ItemsToTake>100</ItemsToTake>
  <ListName>Categories</ListName>
  <IndexListName>CategoriesIndex</IndexListName>
  <Environments hint="list">
    <environment>HabitatShops</environment>
  </Environments>
  <Database>web</Database>
</crawler>
<crawler type="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.Crawlers.SellableItemsCrawler, Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect" patch:source="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connectors.Index.Solr.config">
  <ItemsToTake>100</ItemsToTake>
  <ListName>SellableItems</ListName>
  <IndexListName>SellableItemsIndex</IndexListName>
  <Environments hint="list">
    <environment>HabitatShops</environment>
  </Environments>
  <Database>web</Database>
</crawler>
```

Notice how the environment name being passed in changes between the master & web definitions. This is what controls whether unpublished entities are indexes or not.